# How to put Google Analytics event tracking on a Norton SSL Badge

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'm trying to place a GA Event tag on a Norton SSL script that is running in the footer of the site but I am unable to get it to log to my GA account. The tag works with a Comodo SSL when I place it in the `<li>` but it won't work when I put it in the Norton's `<li>`. Is it possible to tag the Norton SSL or am I just out of luck?

```
<ul class="list-icon">
<li >
<table style="width: 135px;"  title="Click to Verify - This site chose Symantec SSL for secure e-commerce and confidential communications." border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Footer', 'Norton'])">
<tbody >
<tr >
<td align="center" valign="top" width="135">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=www.mrostop.com&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en"></script>
<br /> <a   style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none; font: bold 7px verdana,sans-serif; letter-spacing: .5px; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" href="http://www.symantec.com/ssl-certificates" target="_blank">ABOUT SSL CERTIFICATES</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</li>
<li onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Footer', 'Comodo'])">
<div>
<div align="center">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">// <![CDATA[
TrustLogo("https://www.mrostop.com/images/comodo_secure_100x85_white.png", "CL1", "none");
// ]]></script>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would think about if you want to display this. In my experience, large and reputable companies do not use these widgets, and I see them as a bad sign.

Comment: Also, you should look into external stylesheets, as your code will become far cleaner.